# Objective C Transparent UIViewController for Gameover Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, transparent

Information: I would like to make a little Game (Not Important what kind of game) with a little Game Over Screen.

Because i cant Upload Images, i try to Describe it.

You Play, everything is alright. Then you get Gameover. The Screen should be the Same and an Overlayer is Showing the Score (Transparent / Alpha)

Now my First Question is: Is my Solution good?

I use one UIViewController from the Storyboard

Source:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnTest;
}

-(IBAction)btnTestClick;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MeinGottEh.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)btnTestClick
{
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    MeinGottEh *sampleView = [[MeinGottEh alloc] init];
    sampleView.labelText = @"High: 123";
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Then the Second UIViewController (External File, not in Storyboard)

MeinGottEh.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MeinGottEh : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnClose;
}
-(IBAction)btnCloseClick;
@property(nonatomic) NSString *labelText;

@end
```

MeinGottEh.m

```
#import "MeinGottEh.h"

@interface MeinGottEh ()

@end

@implementation MeinGottEh

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [btnClose setTitle:self.labelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)btnCloseClick
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Is this Solution to Open a Highscore Box good? If no, please tell me how to do it (I make a Research on Stackoverflow. Thats the Most Parts)

If Yes: How can i make it Transparent?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you just try your thought? I recommend to use UIWindow which is `AlertLevel`. Create an `UIWindow` and make the window as key window. Don't forget to set the window's background color clear.

Comment: @AsmarDemir You could use your normal game view controller but add another view on top of it just link the buttons or touches to the view controller you want. That's the method I prefer to use.

Comment: @Asmar Add UIView instead of UIViewController